# Adding objects to ManyToMany field

Tags: django

I have a model called 'Line', which has a ManyToMany relationship with 'User'.
What I am trying to do is to render the form of the line excluding the User field in order to create a costum rendering for the ManyToMany field where the user can search within all the users and then he checks the checkboxes beside the users' names.
Then I read the ids of the selected users and get the users from the database and try to set the users of the new line object.

Here is the code:

### Model:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="line_owners")

    def set_owners(self, users):
        self.owners.clear()
        for user in users:
            self.owners.add(user)
        self.save()
```

### Forms:

```
class LineCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Line
        exclude = 'owners'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(LineCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for filed in self.visible_fields():
            filed.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

### Views:

```
def new_line(request):     
    if request.method == POST:
    form = LineCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            line = form.save()
            if 'line_owner' in request.POST:
                owners_ids = get_integers_from_checked_checkboxes(request, 'line_owner')
                selected_users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=owners_ids)
                line.set_owners(selected_users)

        return redirect(home_page)
```

### The problem:

I tested the users list and it is working fine. The problem is the owners list stays None after calling the 'line.set_owners(selected_users)' function.

Comment: What is `get_integers_from_checked_checkboxes(request, 'line_owner')`? Shouldn't be `owners_ids = get_integers_from_checked_checkboxes(request, 'line_owner')`? Is `owners_ids` correct ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to include it in the code but it is just a function to get the IDs of the checked checkboxes, and it works perfectly fine because I am getting the users well. The problem is only in saving!

Comment: I am not sure field name and field related_name to be the same is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

When using commit=False, you have to call save_m2m().

Comment: I am not using commit = Flase.
I am actually saving the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
line.owners.add(*selected_users)
```

Comment: check `line.id` after `form.save()`.Also check the above line is executing by entering `if` condition.Also check `selected_users` is not empty

Comment: The line is being saved perfectly.
But the ManyToMany filed is not affected by the save function

Comment: check `line.owners.all()` is getting m2m objects